# How do i export an angular app for people without npm?

Tags: angular, deployment

I'm currently working on an Angular app for a school project. The project is finished an easily runnable on console. Sadly our teachers don't have the patience and IT-knowledge to install NPM and get the project running with a console, so i wanted to ask if there is any other way, like an executable, to easily deploy the finished app.

Comment: Go ahead and use some free service like Netlify which allows you to deploy your app in seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run "ng build --prod" command in the console,
this will create a folder named "dist" in your working folder
now you can upload the content of this folder to a hosting server
(there are many free hosting out there)
and give your teacher the link

hope that was helpful
(-;

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to learn how to install, is to easy, I give you the next links:

https://nodejs.org/en/
https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TLhUCjY9iA

The video is the complete guide from cero.